# Kubernetes dashboard in aws EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, kubernetes

I have started 2 ubuntu 16 EC2 instance(one for master and other for worker). Everything working OK. 
I need to setup dashboard to view on my machine. I have copied admin.ctl and executed the script in my machine's terminal

```
 kubectl --kubeconfig ./admin.conf proxy --address='0.0.0.0' --port=8002 --accept-hosts='.*'
```

Everything is fine.
But in browser when I use below link

```
http://localhost:8002/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/
```

I am getting Error: 'dial tcp 192.168.1.23:8443: i/o timeout'
Trying to reach: 'https://192.168.1.23:8443/'

I have enabled all traffics in security policy for aws. What am I missing? Please point me a solution

Answer (score 4):

If you only want to reach the dashboard then it is pretty easy, get the IP address of your EC2 instance and the Port on which it is serving dashboard (`kubectl get services --all-namespaces`) and then reach it using:
First:

`kubectl proxy --address 0.0.0.0 --accept-hosts '.*'`

And in your browswer:

`http://<IP>:<PORT>/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/#!/login`

**Note that this is a possible security vulnerability as you are  accepting all traffic** (AWS firewall rules) and also all connections for your `kubectl proxy` (`--address 0.0.0.0 --accept-hosts '.*'`) so please narrow it down or use different approach. If you have more questions feel free to ask.

Comment: I am getting this Error: **'tls: oversized record received with length 20527' Trying to reach:'10.2##.1.##:9090'** when giving *xxxx:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/ –*

Comment: I see two possibilities here, either you use outdated Kubernetes dashboard - in that case please delete it and install from [official GitHub](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard) page. Or try to change https to http - but I recommend deleting old dashboard and installing the proper one (you can do it for example by `kubectl delete -f *enter old yaml used for dashboard deployment*`. 
If this will not fix the problem please provide results of `kubectl get services --all-namespaces`

Comment: I got inside dashboard, but it is showing some error inside the page in yellow tab.  -->  configmaps is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:kubernetes-dashboard" cannot list resource "configmaps" in API group "" in the namespace "default"  + Show 12 more

Comment: did you reach the site where you should have put the authorization token? 
Also it could be a problem with RBAC. You could try creating a user:
https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/wiki/Creating-sample-user

Comment: Thanks for the support, I added ClusterRoleBinding as my friend suggested. So i can skip token but it will impose security risks. Anyway I can test with this.

Comment: So you succeeded by creating a user for dashboard (as described in the dashboard documentation)? If my answer was helpful consider upvoting or accepting it.

Comment: Worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting http:// in front of *localhost*?

I don't have enough rep to comment, else I would.

Comment: In browser, by default it will take http

Answer (score 0):

For bypassing dashboard with token. You have to execute the below code

```
cat <<EOF | kubectl create -f -
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
  labels:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
  namespace: kube-system
EOF
```

After this you can skip without providing token. But this will cause security issues.